# php-How to compare two sentences in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have two strings :

> str1 = "Hello, this is 1";
>   str2 = "Hello, this is 1";

Now, I need to compare both the sentences and display it inside `<title>` tags, I did this much but don't know how to compare sentences in php.

```
<?php
    $str1 = "Hello, this is 1";
    if ($str1 == "Hello, this is 1")
    {
?>
        <title><?= $str1 ?></title>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
        <title><?= $str2 ?></title>
<?php
    }
?>
```

How can I compare two sentences, and if they are the same, display as the title?

Comment: What do you mean by compare? Do you want to know if they are equal (have the same characters at the same position)?

Comment: @kingkero Yes...if they are equal

Comment: @user3004356 where is $str2 coming from and also what kind of operator it is "<?="

Comment: @RishabhRaj `<?= $var ?>` is equal to `<?php echo $var; ?>`. Check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
<?php if (strcmp ( $str1 ,  "Hello, this is 1" )==0):?> 
<title><? echo $str1; ?></title>
<?php else : ?>
<title><? echo $str2; ?></title>
<?php endif; ?>
```

for more info : [strcmp](https://www.php.net/strcmp)

Answer (score 1):

Compare two strings (case-sensitive):

```
<?php
echo strcmp("Hello world!","Hello world!");
?>
```

Comment: isnot you took it from http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strcmp.asp ? :) also please convert your answer to what actually OP is asking.

Comment: @RishabhRaj i think you already had converted in your own answer, so no need to convert :)

Comment: yeah right i said so because you answered few seconds before than me :) +1

Comment: @RishabhRaj its ok because you made more effort, and the problem has resolved :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to do this

```
<?php
echo strcmp($string1,$string2);
?>
```

Return Value:   This function returns:

```
0 - if the two strings are equal
<0 - if string1 is less than string2
>0 - if string1 is greater than string2
```

Answer (score 0):

use `strcmp()`;

syntax:

```
int strcmp ( string $str1 , string $str2 )
```

read here http://www.php.net/strcmp

so now your code will look like this :

```
<?php 
$str1="Hello, this is 1";
$str2="something";
$a=strcmp($str1,$str2);
if($a==0){?>   //if both strings are equal
<title><?php echo $str1?></title>
<?php }else{?>
<title><?php echo $str2?></title>
<?php }?>
```